# I don't get why this @selector isn't working

Tags: ios, uiview, action, selector, uigesturerecognizer

I am creating several `UIView`'s which I add a `UITapGestureRecognizer` with an `action` thats suppose to call a method in the `viewController`, but it doesn't seem to work.

```
-(void)setupFreeMoneyView {
    NSArray *array = @[@"Facebook", @"Twitter", @"SMS", @"Email"];
    int index = 0;
    for (NSString *str in array) {
        UIImageView *imgView = [[UIImageView alloc] initWithFrame:CGRectMake(100*index++, 0, 100, 100)];
        [imgView setImage:[UIImage imageNamed:[NSString stringWithFormat:@"%@Logo", str]]];
        [imgView addGestureRecognizer:[[UITapGestureRecognizer alloc]
                                   initWithTarget:self
                                   action:NSSelectorFromString([NSString stringWithFormat:@"postTo%@", str])]];
        [freeView addSubview:imgView];
    }
}
```

`freeView` is a `UIView` created in the `MainStoryboard`.

Ive checked if its the `NSSelectorFromString()` by using a normal `@selector()` thats not working but it isn't the cause.

It does work if I change the line `[imgView addGestureRecognizer:...` to `[freeView addGestureRecognizer:...]`

I just don't seem to understand why this is happening.

Comment: u need to set userInteractionEnabled=YES because it by default to NO. so the touch interaction wil received by imageView

Comment: Look at your iniiWithTarget: argument. That's the object whose selector you are trying to call. Be sure it matches the one that does implement the selectors you are after.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

try this

`imgView.userInteractionEnabled = YES ;`

`userInteractionEnabled` of `UIImageView` is set to NO by default.

Answer (score 1):

maybe you need set userInteractionEnabled = YES for the UIImageView